# Resource names changed in REST server

Tags: hyperledger-fabric, hyperledger, hyperledger-composer, ibm-blockchain

I've got my Hyperledger network running for about ~3 months. Since yesterday the REST API started to throw errors. The targeted resources could not be found (404).

Apparently the REST routes changed from:

**/resource**

to

**/org.acme.network.resource**

The network is running on a Azure virtual machine. How is this sudden change possible? I did not update anything. Also, how can I revert the routes to the previous convention?

Comment: sounds like you chose different options at startup of the REST server eg. "Specify if you want namespaces in the generated REST API: " - use 'never use namespaces' and you should see the 'former' REST API endpoints

Comment: @PaulO'Mahony That was it. I never considered this would be the issue. Thanks for the help.